# Having problem with .addClass function on Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown

I want to change font style with dropdown. And this fiddle works fine but won't work properly on the page. I think I'm having `.addClass` problem. Or I can't get the option names.. No idea

https://jsfiddle.net/mc2xd63o/

It works great on a simple page: https://roarcraft.com.tr/pages/kisisellestirme

But I got stuck adding code to this page: https://roarcraft.com.tr/collections/deri-anahtarlik/products/yarasa-deri-anahtarlik-2-adet

There is a plugin which triggered with `<div id="infiniteoptions-container"></div>` code and I am not able to change class names. Couldnt figured out where the mistake is..

Comment: Add your code as a snippet, not a link. The link might become dead or unavailable to some users.

Answer (score 0):

for me, this is a typical case where you have to use the css variables

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

sample code

```js
const Root    = document.documentElement
    , fontSel = document.querySelector('#select-font')

fontSel.onchange=_=>{
  Root.style.setProperty('--choosed-font', fontSel.value)
}
```

```css
:root {
  --choosed-font  : "Courier new";
}
#test {
  font-family: var(--choosed-font);
}
#lorem {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: .2em;
  font-family: var(--choosed-font);
}
```

```html
<input id="test" type="text" value="test">

<select id="select-font">
  <option value="Courier new" selected>Courier</option>
  <option value="Arial" >Arial</option>
  <option value="Times" >Times</option>
</select>

<div id="lorem">
  Ideoque fertur neminem aliquando ob haec vel similia poenae addictum oblato de more elogio revocari iussisse,
  quod inexorabiles quoque principes factitarunt. et exitiale hoc vitium, quod in aliis non numquam intepescit, 
  in illo aetatis progressu effervescebat, obstinatum eius propositum accendente adulatorum cohorte.
</div>
```